# How do we include a variable in escaped double quotes?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB, and I'm trying to perform a `$search` on a `$text` field from a collection. As mentioned in the docs, *To match on a phrase, as opposed to individual terms, enclose the phrase in escaped double quotes (\"), as in:
"\"ssl certificate\""*

I have a variable `query` that holds the value inputted by a user in a simple text search application. I want to add this query as a phrase, so that I can perform my search on all the words entered by the user appropriately.

Is there anyway one can achieve this?

Comment: the relevant part of your code would help give more precise answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the user input is in the variable `input` you can add double qoutes around it like so:

```
input = '"'+input+'"';
```

this string, you should then be able to use in your `$search`.
If you post your code, I could try to give a more specific answer.

Comment: This worked. I just added the escaped quotes to match what the mongodb docs required : 
var reg= "\""+query+"\""

Comment: Glad I could help.  I think `"\""` and `'"'` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex of the format `/regexString/g` you can also create [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) objects using variables.

```
var regexExp = new RegExp(query,"g");
```

You can use this `regexExp` to search.

Comment: I did try this solution, but it was not returning the documents I required. Thanks for the help anyway!